# cocoa: how to make a image button like app store

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

Instead of push button, I want to implement a image button like app store, as you can see in the image bellow:

[image]

after I click Featured image button, the image turns blue.
My question is:

1. how to make a image button?
2. how turn the color after click it?

I can add a image into a square button, but it doesn't like the app store button.
[image]

Comment: +1. I'm a newbie with osx/ios development environment. There's really very few tutorials in the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another image - blue image and just change it using `-setImage` in button's action (example at the bottom). Use **Gradient Button's style** (It can be changed in *Attributes Inspector -> Style*) then You can change button's size easily. Don't forget to choose button's type to **Momentary Change** (it will remove white background when pushing button). Also remove border, unchecking *Attributes Inspector -> Visual -> bordered checkbox*. Add alternate Image (Your blue image).

Example: (when button is clicked it will be changed to blue image)

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    [buttonOutlet setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"yourBlueImageFromResources"]];
}
```

**Note:** don't forget to `IBOutlet` button to buttonOutlet.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I've been looking around for a day and I can't find much information on it. I can create a image button now, thank you!!!